# conflict with hibernate-search-orm with other Dependencies

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate-search

there is an Issue while adding *org.hibernate* dependency in pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>get-user-permissions</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> 
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jdk.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdk.tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.5.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.11</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
            <version>5.10.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Error List caused by and Error Message**

> [ERROR] 2018-07-10 15:48:45.908 [main]
>   org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure(SpringApplication.java:842)
>   - Application run failed
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/hibernate/resource/beans/spi/ManagedBeanRegistry
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>         at
>
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
>   ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
>   ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
>   [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
>             at com.greydelta.GreydeltaErpApplication.main(GreydeltaErpApplication.java:19)
>   [classes/:?]
>           Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/resource/beans/spi/ManagedBeanRegistry
>             at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator.integrate(HibernateSearchIntegrator.java:55)
>   ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.10.2.Final.jar:5.10.2.Final]
>             at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:281)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>             at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>             at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             ... 16 more
>           Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.resource.beans.spi.ManagedBeanRegistry
>             at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
>             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
>             at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
>             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
>             at org.hibernate.search.hcore.impl.HibernateSearchIntegrator.integrate(HibernateSearchIntegrator.java:55)
>   ~[hibernate-search-orm-5.10.2.Final.jar:5.10.2.Final]
>             at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:281)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>             at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>             at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
>   ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341)
>   ~[spring-orm-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1765)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
>   ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
>             ... 16 more

Comment: have you tried using `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` for possible conflicts?

Comment: i am new to java/Spring. trying to learn.
dont know much about that

Comment: The command I've provided is not related to Spring or Java, but to Maven. You can run it into terminal / console --> https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: $ mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose
bash: mvn: command not found

Comment: you have not configured your maven variable as path, read this -> https://maven.apache.org/install.html

Comment: Use an older version. This one relies on hibernate 5.3 (judging from the stacktrace) whereas spring boot has 5.2.

Comment: have you tried upgrading to version 2.0.3 of spring boot

Comment: yes @user3624390  it did't help

Comment: You just try to add this line <version>5.3.2.Final</version> to hibernate-entity-manager

Comment: nothing happned @tahir-hussain-mir

Answer (score 7, accepted):

5.9.2.Final

Use this version in pom.Xml file.
Don't use 5.10.2